# Insert data in SQLite in a specific interval time

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, python-multithreading

I have a python process which executes some jobs. The program must have executed in loop. It receive data from serial port, executes processing over data and, every 1 second store data in Sqlite.

I read many posts about threading using Timer object, but i can't fix the problem.
The structure basics the code is:

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
import json
import serial
from threading import Timer 

#global variables
sqlpath = 'db.sqlite3'

def insertdata(sqlpath,data):
    #insert data in sqlite

def process_data(strdata):
    #process serial information

t = Timer(1,insertdata,[sqlpath,data])
t.start()

if __name=='__main__':
    while True:
        serial_str = serialport.readline()
        #process data
        data = process_data(serial_str)
```

I have 2 problems:
1 - The data is refresh inside loop. How to pass the data to callback function?
2 - The callback function (in this code) executes 1 time only

Any idea to solve this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no guarantee that the `data` is ready if the`Timer` become ready.

Comment: Does it have to be serialport? Does it have to be batch processed every second? Could you implement a queueing functionality to eliminate some of the timing headaches?

Comment: Anyone have any solution?

Comment: Yes, it's a real time process, and i need to save the data every 1 second.